# Dirac’s debt to Hamilton

Tags: quantum-mechanics, dirac, quaternions

According to Tobias Hurter’s popular exposition *Too Big for a Single Mind* (narrated in the present tense):

> Dirac makes use of an elegant mathematical tool developed by the Irish mathematician William Hamilton in the nineteenth century.

This is from a passage discussing Dirac in Cambridge in the summer of 1925; see pages 127-128.

What “elegant mathematical tool” is Hurter talking about? Was it quaternions? Unfortunately the notes at the back of the book do not say anything more about this episode.

Comment: Schrödinger already used Hamiltonian dynamics before Dirac, see [Did wave optics anticipate quantum mechanics?](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/a/3493/55), as did Heisenberg in 1926. Heisenberg's way of representing quantum mechanical energy operators as "quantizations" of classical Hamiltonians is now called [canonical quantization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canonical_quantization). Dirac's innovation was to extend the idea to quantum fields in 1927, what is now called [second quantization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second_quantization).

Comment: @Conifold  think it is referring to Clifford algebras and quaternions and not to Hamiltonians.

Comment: I don’t know if Hurter is correct, but I stress that he is writing about Dirac in 1925, not 1927.

Comment: Judging by "stumbles upon differential operator that, like matrices, satisfies Heisenberg's multiplication rule" and "no more matrices" in the surrounding passage, Hurter is talking about Dirac's paper [The fundamental equations of quantum mechanics](https://royalsocietypublishing.org/doi/10.1098/rspa.1925.0150) submitted in 1925. There he draws parallels between algebras of quantum commutators and Poisson brackets and writes matrix-free Hamilton's equations in the anti-symmetric form for both cases.

Comment: @Mauricio You probably mean [gamma matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_matrices), but those are from 1928.

Answer (score 3):

I'd wager that the ambiguous reference is to the appearance of Hamiltonian *quaternions* (as an instance of a Clifford algebra) in Dirac's construction of a square root (of a certain sort) of a/the Laplacian, which is nowadays called a/the "Dirac operator". (Not to be confused with Dirac's $\delta$.) It is a linear differential operator with coefficients in a Clifford algebra related to a quadratic form attached to the geometry of the situation.

This is quite different from square roots of positive unbounded self-adjoint operators on Hilbert spaces... For example, the Dirac operator still has a robust distributional sense, while the unbounded-op-on-Hilbert-space version is not distributional.

The Hamiltonian quaternions arise as a Clifford algebra attached to a low-dimensional quadratic form.

Comment: With the OP specification of the dating to 1925, the Dirac operator is unlikely, it is [from 1928](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_operator). The surrounding passage also talks about a paper sent to Göttingen in 1925, which I think was a draft of [this one](https://royalsocietypublishing.org/doi/10.1098/rspa.1925.0150), where he draws analogies between commutators and Poisson brackets in Hamiltonian dynamics.

Comment: @Conifold, ah, yes, with the dates, you're surely right. But then, as in your earlier comment, it is mildly curious that Schroedinger didn't/doesn't get more credit...

Comment: @paulgarrett : "This is quite different from square roots of positive unbounded self-adjoint operators on Hilbert spaces... For example, the Dirac operator still has a robust distributional sense, while the unbounded-op-on-Hilbert-space version is not distributional." Could you please explain what you mean or give a reference? This is not a critique, just trying to understand.

Comment: @akhmeteli, the functional calculus for unbounded but _positive_ operators such as (a/the self-adjoint extension of...) $-\Delta$ (... restricted to test functions) gives a (positive) square root, yes, but that square root is no longer a differential operator. In contrast, Dirac operators _are_ differential operators, although with coefficients in non-commuting scalars (Hamiltonian quaternions, or, in general, Clifford algebras).

Comment: @paulgarrett : Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

The OP noted in a comment:

> I don’t know if Hurter is correct, but I stress that he is writing
> about Dirac in 1925, not 1927.

Therefore, the text is probably about Dirac's 1925 [article](https://royalsocietypublishing.org/doi/10.1098/rspa.1925.0150) , where Dirac uses Hamiltonian function. The equations of motion then feature the Poisson bracket. The Dirac's general approach to quantization involves the replacement of the Poisson brackets by commutators.